# Getting error in histogram - I am trying to plot the count

Tags: r, ggplot2

Below is a simple example. I am finding difficulty in creating histogram.

1. I am getting error -

```
Error: StatBin requires a continuous x variable: the x variable is discrete.Perhaps you want stat="count"?
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

2. How do I plot the percentage of each alphabet ?

```
library(tidyverse)

# generate random alphabets
code <- sample(x = c("a", "b", "c"),
               size = 100)

tbl <- tibble(code)

# plot histogram of alphabets
ggplot(data = tbl,
       aes(x = code)) + 
  geom_histogram()
```

Comment: You should use `geom_histogram(stat="count")`

Comment: Thanks, how do I get proportion or percentage?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to plot counts of a categorical variable, you need a *bar plot*. This is different from a histogram, which shows counts within bins of a *continuous* variable:

```r
library(tidyverse)

tbl <- tibble(code = sample(x = c("a", "b", "c"), size = 100, replace = TRUE))

ggplot(tbl, aes(x = code)) + 
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

If you want percentages instead of counts on the y axis, you can do:

```r
ggplot(tbl, aes(x = code)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = after_stat(count / nrow(tbl)))) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>